# exclude name in citation latex in thesis

Tags: biblatex

I'm compiling my thesis on LaTeX and in a quote I would need not to display the name but only the year of publication, as in this example:

> you can read the text of Bregman (1990)

instead, I get:

> you can read the text of Bregman (Bregman 1990)

I am attaching the part of the code that I have set up for the management of the bibliography, thanks

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle, sorting=nty, bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}
```

Comment: What command are you using to cite? Do you write `you can read the text of \textcite{bregman}` or `you can read the text of \citeauthor{bregman} \autocite*{bregman}` or something else?

Comment: hi and thanks, just  \cite{bregman}

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but the setup `style=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle, sorting=nty,` is a bit unusual. With author-year citations I'd also use an author-year setup in the bibliography. But `bibstyle=authortitle,` forces the year to move towards the end of the bibliography entry (making it slightly less prominent and thus harder to find an entry if there are several works by the same set of authors) and `sorting=nty,` even makes sure that entries are sorted by name, title and then year, so that your readers may have a hard time finding the entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\textcite` to get a citation in the format `<Author> (<Year>)` or you can use `\autocite*` to get only `(<year>)`. The latter can then be combined with `\citeauthor` or a manual mention of the author name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}

Dolor \autocite{nussbaum}

Lorem \citeauthor{sigfridsson} \autocite*{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)//Dolor (Nussbaum 1978)//Lorem Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)]

Instead of `\autocite*` you could also use `\parencite*`; there is also `\cite*`.

---

Note that I simplified the style setup and switched to a true author-year style in the bibliography and citations. The MWE also uses Biber and not BibTeX. But that is just to make the MWE more straightforward, the core of the answer is `\textcite` and `\autocite*`.